前に まで までに after verbs
Please explain what is the difference between:

君が来る前に元気だった
君が来るまでに元気だった
君が来るまで元気だった

Well, i know about the difference of まで and までに、 までに and 前に, and, it seems that questions on a similar topic were answered here, but  but I got confused in these sentences.
in the first - just like "before"? in the second - “until you came”, but not necessarily that it got worse immediately after he arrived (maybe a little earlier). but in the third - right after. Am i right?


Sentence 1 is unnatural without は, but after fixing this, it's like this:

君が来る前には元気だった。
It was in good condition (at a certain time point shortly) before you came.

A sentence like this implies either its condition is unstable or the speaker only knows about its temporary condition (i.e., "last time I checked before you came...").

Sentence 2 is unnatural. See this question about the difference between まで and までに: What's the difference between まで and までに?

Sentence 3 is the most straightforward.

君が来るまで元気だった。
It was in good condition until you came.

This implies it's no longer in good condition.



EDIT: Looks like whether an action/state continues is the key.

AまでB means the an action or state continues until A.

23時まで寝る。
I'll sleep until 23:00.
3月まで学生です。
I am a student until March.
彼が来るまで元気だった。
She was fine until he came.
3日後まで忘れます。/ 3日後まで忘れています。
I'll keep it off my mind for the next 3 days (then I'll work on it again).


AまでにB means you do B by/before A. B is an (instant or state-change) action.

23時までに寝る。
I'll go to bed by 23:00.
5年後までにお金持ちになります。
I'll become rich within 5 years.
彼が来るまでに元気になった。
She had recovered before he came.
3日後までに忘れます。
I'll forget about it within 3 days (although I can't forget it today).




I wonder what's wrong with 2. How would you say "By the time you came, it was in good condition"? For example, opening a bottle of red wine. It starts to improve after you open it but gets worse again if you leave it too long.  Is it that までに doesn't go well with だった? How about 君が来るまでに元気になっていた?

@user3856370 までに is for specifying a deadline. "By the time you came, it (the wine) was in good condition" is "君が来たころ(に)は良い状態だった". "君が来るまでに元気になっていた" sounds unnatural to me, too.

and as for 前には, how does the particle は change the situation? we should add it, because of  だった?

Is it okay if I ask about my examples for understanding?

２３時前に寝なければならない　ー ok
２３時まで寝なければならない　ー not ok
２３時までに寝なければならない　ー ok (not sure)
is that right?


@DmitriiHude You don't need は if Sentence 1 is used in a relative clause (君が来る前に元気だった女の子 is fine), so I think it's a topic particle you always need in a main clause. As for ～時まで寝る vs ～時までに寝る, please see the edit. 23時前に寝る is "to go to bed shortly before 23:00 (e.g., 22:50)".

@user3856370 Sorry, "君が来るまでに元気になっていた" is okay when 君's arrival is treated as some sort of "deadline". "君が来るまでに元気だった" sounds odd.

@naruto so, if i would say, 君が来る前に彼女は元気だった is ok? because there is a particle in this sentence

@DmitriiHude Yes, that's perfectly fine, and it's basically the same as Sentence 1 except that it has an explicit topic.
